# Как получить название всех файлов с определенным расширением во всех папках, с++

Tags: c++

Нужно получить название всех файлов с расширением .txt во всех папках начиная с C:\\ и вывести ответы в консоль. Спасибо.

Comment: Разве это не гуглится?

Comment: Я бы не писал сюда, если бы нашел что то.

Comment: Странно Вы ищите: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-files-in-a-directory-using-c-or-cplusplus

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/recursive_directory_iterator

Comment: @Виктор выводит только там где запускался файл

Comment: Ну Вы уж сообразите, как вызывать с корня , например с диска С:\

Comment: Даже если так, ищется только в каталоге C:\\, а не во всех остальных папках начиная с C:\\

Comment: @John `directory_iterator` - в одном каталоге. `recursive_directory_iterator` - во всех папках.